# Selenium grid installed in kubernetes cluster could not open selenium:chrome browser when test are executed from local machine

Tags: kubernetes, selenium-webdriver, testing, selenium-grid, testcafe

I have installed selenium grid (version 4.8.0) in Kubernetes cluster and when executing the testcafe tests as a job in the cluster, sessions are getting created and tests are getting executed successfully.

When I try to run the tests from local or from CI pipeline,  session is getting created in the grid, but fails with below error

```
ERROR Unable to open the "selenium:chrome" browser due to the following error:

    Error: ECONNRESET socket hang up
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/index.js:295:15)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnEnd (node:_http_client:520:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)

Type "testcafe -h" for help.
```

If there is version compatibility issue, tests must not have worked when executed within the cluster. If there is a networks issue, then sessions must not have got created from local. Please help on this.